# Javascript - Cannot set property 'backgroundColor'

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I'm trying to make a website, but I'm having a problem. When I run it in Chrome I get: "Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined". I don't understand why I'm getting this. My var is not an array (just an id). I've been googling it for 2 hours but nothing helps me.

Here's my HTML code:

```js
    $(document).ready
    (
 function()
 {
  $("#go").bind("click", remonte)
    }
    );

    function remonte(){ 
 $("#menu").animate({marginTop: "-460"}, 500);
 $("#ar").animate({marginTop: "120"}, 500);
 $("#reste").animate({height: "500", marginTop: "-50"},400);
 $("#go").remove(); 
 setTimeout(charge, 510);  
    }

    function charge(){
        $('#reste').load("about.html",'',montreNouveauContenu);
        $("#surmenu").style.backgroundColor="transparent"; //HERE
        $("#menu_jaune").animate({width: "900"}, 500);
    }

    function montreNouveauContenu() {  
 $('#content').show('normal');  
    }  
    function suppr(){
 $("#dev").remove();
 $("#reste").remove();
 $("#content").remove();
 $("#bandeau_graphisme").animate({height: "255"},500);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
 <head>
  <title>Folio</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="anim2.js"></script>   
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="tout">
   <img id="menu_jaune" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x200/000/fff" alt="le menu"/></td>
   <div id="bandeau_graphisme">
    <img id="dev" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x200/000/fff" alt="image de couverture du site"/>
   </div>
   <div id="surmenu">
    <div id="menu">
     <img id="ar" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x200/000/fff" alt="ar"/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="go">
    <p id="wtf">HERE WE GO! Click Here</p>
   </div>
   <div id="reste">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19):

It's because a jQuery object doesn't have a `style` property.

```
    // ---------v----???
$("#surmenu").style.backgroundColor="transparent"; //HERE
```

---

It should be like this:

```
$("#surmenu").css("backgroundColor", "transparent");
```

---

If you wanted to use the DOM API, you could do a traditional DOM selection:

```
document.getElementById("surmenu").style.backgroundColor="transparent";
```

Comment: Got a headache as I wasn't seeing change... Turned out caching was enabled (new build and forgot to turn it off in DevTools). Just worth pointing out in case people get the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a jQuery object, not an element, so it has no `style` property. You want this:

```
$("#surmenu")[0].style.backgroundColor="transparent"; //HERE
```

or this ...

```
$("#surmenu").get(0).style.backgroundColor="transparent"; //HERE
```

or this ...

```
$("#surmenu").css( 'background-color', 'transparent' ); //HERE
```